# How to add link to Comment Author's User Profile page

Tags: users

The below code is from the comment.tpl.php file:

```
<div class="comment-avartar">
<?php print $picture ?>
<div class="submitted"><?php print render($content['submitted_by'] ['#markup']);?></a></div>
```

I want "$content['submitted_by'] ['#markup']" to link to the user profile of the user who posted the comment.

i have tried editing the code to something like this:

```
<?php $link = drupal_get_path_alias('user/' . $user->uid);?>

<div class="comment-avartar">
<?php print $picture ?>
<div class="submitted"><a href="<?php $link ;?>"><?php print render($content['submitted_by'] ['#markup']);?></a></div>
```

But it links to the user profile of the currently logged in user.

What I would like is to link it to the profile of the Comment author.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you enable in theme settings for "User pictures in comments" to be check marked?

Answer (score 0):

Comment module does add a link to comment author name on comments view. The link is conditionally visible to user's i.e. If user has permission to "**View user profiles**" or administrative permission then he will be able to see author name as link, else plain text. See screenshots below (tested with **Anonymous** user with and without permission "View User Profiles"):

**Permissions:**
[image]

**Comment preview with permission:**

[image]

**Comment preview without permission:**

[image]

You can still add a link to author name by your own, by implementing **template_preprocess_comment()** function in your theme's **template.php** or **.module** file. This might lead to access denied page:

```
/**
 * Process variables for comment.tpl.php.
 *
 * @see comment.tpl.php
 */
function [THEME_NAME]_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {
  if (!empty($variables['elements']['#comment']->uid)) {
    $variables['comment_author'] = l($variables['elements']['#comment']->name, 'user/1/' . $variables['elements']['#comment']->uid);
  }
  else {
    $variables['comment_author'] = t('Anonymous');
  }
}
```

And then printing "**$comment_author**" variable in comment.tpl.php file, see below.

```
<p class="commenter-name">
  <?php print $comment_author; ?>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It works as you have outlined. However using your approach, it is the "username" that links to the user profile. In my case, i have edited the "submitted by" value to custom fields (first & last name). That is why i added the <a> tag.

Comment: Glad, it helped...

Comment: Thanks for this. It works as you have outlined. However using your approach, it is the "username" that links to the user profile. In my case, i have edited the "submitted by" value to custom fields (first & last name). That is why i added the <a> tag. –